# How do I set transaction as digital good PayPal PHP Example

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Hello I'm using https://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration so my customers can upgrade their accounts directly through my website. My mistake was that the transactions were being made as physical goods, and now PayPal is requiring proof of fulfillment.

If anyone knows how I would change that PHP example to be for Digital Goods, I would sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [request body](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body), set `application_context` to an object with a `shipping_preference` of `NO_SHIPPING`

Comment: Alright I set as such https://i.imgur.com/Es3jp7V.png. Hopefully this is the correct way to do it, if not please let me know. Otherwise, I appreciate your help and have a great day.